# How do I create an XY graph in Windows Forms app?

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to create a graph in a Form in Visual Studio.
I have a constant stream of data coming in via a COM port and would like to create a "live plotter" feature in my program.
I can see the "Chart" option in the toolbox when I create a new form, but it is greyed out.
Can I create a chart() object in Windows Forms?

I was trying to drag-and-drop a "Chart" from the toolbox onto a new form, but the option for "Chart" was greyed out.

Comment: How is the data being saved?

Comment: It is being pickled in .txt format. I wish to create an X-Y chart that uses the data as it is coming thru the stream to place a dot on a chart, similar to MATLAB functionality. There is too much data to save it in a list or array.

Comment: You want to plot in real-time a stream of data from a serial port. Without dumping it somewhere, the task will be a difficult as no reporting systems in VS takes as a DataSource a memory stream.